# azure service fabric web api's web address

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-appfabric

I m new to service fabric .I have created a web api on Microsoft service fabric which works as expected in local environment .

1.where can i see the application config values for the web api ?

2.what would be the api's url ?

Comment: How did you create the web api service, did you use a template? The address can be found in the ServiceManifest.xml file of the stateless service , like  `<Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="8251" />`

Comment: Try to read documentations before asking here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore